# Do we have too many 90-degree angles in our residentHVAC design?

Tags: hvac

QUESTION:  Are three 90-degree angles in the HVAC ductwork layout in our new construction home too many?   While we certainly require some 90-degree angles to get around the central open stairwell (see attached image), I'm concerned that we may have so many angles in some branch lines as to unnecessarily restrict the airflow.   Thanks for any counsel that you can offer!

[image: 90 degree angles]

Comment: Right angle takeoffs from the main trunk are very common.  I wouldn't worry about that.  But I would question why some of the runs double back on themselves, like the two horizontal blue branch lines running left to right on your diagram.  I don't know why they wouldn't have tied the two right most blue branch lines directly into the main green trunk.

Comment: Are you sure those corners are right angle and not some sort of curved elbow?  Maybe the square corners are just notional and they may be curved in practice.

Comment: @SteveSh Well, of course non-takeoff right angles would be radiused, nobody would do it otherwise. But I have many concerns with OPs drawing, it is incomplete, it does not show where any registers are. It shows the main trunk getting narrower but no reason why, i.e. no take-offs. As it stands, it looks like the initial part of the blue branch is really a main trunk. The circuitous route of the ductwork would make me worry about some runs overall length especially the upper right one. A more complete accurate drawing might help.

Comment: Another question for OP, who created this drawing, is it just notional? How is the ductwork being implemented? For example; flex-duct throughout, or ridged metal for the main trunk with flex for the branches? At any rate, wherever flex is being used there can't really be any right angles (except at a takeoff) and it should be radiused as gently as possible while also being pulled as tight as possible. And one other question, where is the duct-work; ceiling/attic, basement/crawlspace, etc.?

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback!  I'm not at the jobsite, so I can't answer all your questions, but I can clarify that the reason that they didn't run "the two right most blue branch lines directly into the main green trunk" is because the lines are embedded within the floor trusses and they chose to travel AROUND a partial LVL beam that stands in the way.   (The architect made clear that we could install a cut-out through that LVL, but this apparentlly wasn't communicated to the installer.)  I'm fine with this amended more circuitous design as long as the addt'l 90's don't pose a problem.

Comment: The drawing which I provided IS only notional to demonstrate the circuitous route of some of the duct runs.   All ductwork except the bathroom vents are sheetmetal.    The ductwork is located within the 16"-high floor trusses between the walkout and main levels.

Comment: @ReevesBrown Ok, good info. A professional HVAC designer will use formulas and spreadsheets to design your ductwork, one of the main concerns is overall duct length and the length of each run. Here, 90 degree (radiused) bends add a certain length (say 10') to the duct run calcs. As long as the designer has taken this into account it should not be a problem.

Comment: The ducts seem kind of long, please highlight the excluded area in your plan.